# Office Js providing wrong attachment ID while dragging and dropping email from shared mailbox to own mailbox in Outlook Client

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

Office Js is providing the wrong attachment id when user drag and drop any email from shared mailbox to his own mailbox. It is happening only in outlook desktop client.it may be happening due to id cache in client. When application check on browser it provides the correct attachment id.

Due to this bug our Add-in functionality is not working as expected.

Comment: For that I'd suggest filing an issue on the `OfficeJS` repo in GitHub instead.

Comment: I have already raise a bug. but still looking if someone else have faced this issue or have workaround.